# Instance Scheduler Creation fails in any region other than N.Virginia

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

While trying to create Instance Scheduler using terraform, the code works fine for N. Virginia but it fails in Oregon. It fails for app_autoscaling_policy. It works for Readpolicy but for Writepolicy it gives error that too only for one region

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "StateTableAutoScalingReadPolicy" {
  name               = "${var.general_config.ProjectName}-StateTableAutoScalingReadPolicy"
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.StateTableAutoScalingReadTarget.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.StateTableAutoScalingReadTarget.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.StateTableAutoScalingReadTarget.service_namespace

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    target_value = 75
    scale_in_cooldown = 60
    scale_out_cooldown = 60
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization"
    }
  }
  depends_on = [aws_appautoscaling_target.StateTableAutoScalingReadTarget]
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "StateTableAutoScalingWriteTarget" {
  max_capacity       = local.settings.appASTmax
  min_capacity       = local.settings.appASTmin
  resource_id        = "table/${aws_dynamodb_table.StateTable.id}"
  scalable_dimension = "dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits" # #dynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization
  service_namespace  = "dynamodb"
  role_arn           = aws_iam_role.SchedulerDynamoDBScalingRole.arn

  depends_on = [aws_appautoscaling_target.StateTableAutoScalingReadTarget]
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "StateTableAutoScalingWritePolicy" {
  depends_on = [aws_appautoscaling_target.StateTableAutoScalingWriteTarget]
  name               = "${var.general_config.ProjectName}-StateTableAutoScalingWritePolicy"
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.StateTableAutoScalingWriteTarget.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.StateTableAutoScalingWriteTarget.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.StateTableAutoScalingWriteTarget.service_namespace

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    target_value = 75
    scale_in_cooldown = 60
    scale_out_cooldown = 60
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization"
    }
  }
}
```

```
Error: Failed to create scaling policy: Error putting scaling policy: ValidationException: Only one TargetTrackingScaling policy for a given metric specification is allowed
```

Comment: You seem to be using `DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization` for both. What happens if you change that to the write equivalent for `StateTableAutoScalingWritePolicy`?

Comment: I haven't tried. But if that is the issue how is it working in N.Virginia?

Comment: I'm not sure but you'd need to update the question to include a full [mcve] for anyone to be able to dig into that really.

Comment: Not ```StateTableAutoScalingWritePolicy``` but ```DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization``` worked. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Read Policy and Write Policy both were using the predefined metric type as DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization.
After modifying it to DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization in one, it worked.